# font-size style doesn't work for jsf selectOneRadio

Tags: css, jsf-2

I can't modify the font size of the itemLabel in selectOneRadio in jsf, I can change color but not the size.

here is my code:

```
<h:selectOneRadio style="color:red; font-size:7pt;"
    value="#{myBean.choice}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="one" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="two" itemValue="2" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="three" itemValue="3" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

is their any idea to resolve that?
thank you for your help.

My config: jsf 2 and tomcat 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work fine. Please check the generated HTML with help of among others Firebug. The `<h:selectOneRadio>` generates a HTML `<table>` element with the labels in `<td>` elements. Apparently you've in some CSS stylesheet a declaration something like

```
td {
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

which get precedence over the inline `font-size:7pt;` declaration on the `<table>` element. You'd need to finetune the CSS. This is best to be done by supplying a normal CSS style class (using inline CSS is a bad practice anyway):

```
<h:selectOneRadio styleClass="choices">
```

with

```
.choices td {
    color: red;
    font-size: 7pt;
}
```